# Weird white bar when embedding a UISearchController on the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to create a simple search view with a `UISearchController`embedded on the UITableView. For this to work, I've set the `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdge.None`. This creates the following result:

[image: Weird white bar]

If I set the `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdge.All` or `UIEdgeRect.Top`, the white bar will be gone but the table view will continuously shift down every time I click on the search bar and then on cancel:

[image: Blank space]

[image: It get's bigger]

Any idea on what might be happening here? This is my first use of `UISearchController` so I'm a bit clueless on what do do here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out TPKeyboardAvoiding and UISearchController don't play well together. Removing TPKeyboardAvoiding solved the issue.